# What are equations on mathematica and differences between these errors?

Tags: functions, function-construction, fitting

These are the three errors I was given. I so far wrote the code which was computing the polynomial interpolation but now I am asked to find those three norms: 
norm error 
mean norm error
maximal absolute error

This is code I found that computers interpolation without the built in.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_] = x e^-x - 1
f[1];
f[2];
f[3];
f[4];

XY = {{1, -1 + 1/e}, {2, -1 + 2/e^2}, {3, -1 + 3/e^3}, {4, -1 + 4/e^4}};
p4[x_] = Fit[XY, {1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4}, x]
dots = ListPlot[XY, PlotStyle -> {PointSize[0.02]}];
gr5 = Plot[{f[x], p4[x]}, {x, -0.6, 2.1}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}];

Show[gr5, dots, PlotRange -> {{0, 1.2}, {0.0, 1.15}}]
```

Answer (score 5):

First, a basic mistake: in *Mathematica*, the natural log base is entered as `E` (or as Esc e Esc), and *not* plain `e`. And many folks prefer `Exp[x]` to `E^x`.

Also, your lines `f[1];`, `f[2];`, etc., since they end with semicolons, just suppress the output from them.

Second, even with that corrected, everything is fine until your final `Show`, where you have so restricted your `PlotRange` as to exclude everything.

This works:

```
    f[x_] := x Exp[-x] - 1
    f[{1, 2, 3, 4}]
    XY = {{1, -1 + 1/E}, {2, -1 + 2/E^2}, {3, -1 + 3/E^3}, {4, -1 + 4/E^4}};

(* Out: {-1 + 1/E, -1 + 2/E^2, -1 + 3/E^3, -1 + 4/E^4}  *)

    p4[x_] = Fit[XY, {1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4}, x];
    dots = ListPlot[XY, PlotStyle -> {PointSize[0.02]}];
    gr5 = Plot[{f[x], p4[x]}, {x, -0.6, 2.1}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}];
    Show[dots, gr5]
```

[image: Figure 1]

```
    Show[gr5, dots, PlotRange -> {{0, 1.2}, {-0.75, -0.5}}, 
          AxesOrigin -> {0, -0.5}]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Thank you for the corrections as well! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"];

f[x_] = x E^-x - 1; (* Note `E` vice `e` *)

XY = {#, f[#]} & /@ Range[4]

(* {{1, -1 + 1/E}, {2, -1 + 2/E^2}, {3, -1 + 3/E^3}, {4, -1 + 4/E^4}} *)

p4[x_] = Fit[XY, {1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4}, x]

(* -0.589552 - 0.0147616 x - 0.0248196 x^2 - 0.00460293 x^3 + 0.00161548 x^4 *)

Plot[{p4[x], f[x]}, {x, 0, 4},
 PlotStyle -> {Green, Red},
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {0.75, 0.75}],
 Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02], Point[XY]}]
```

[image]

Adding a point for `x == 0`

```
XY2 = {#, f[#]} & /@ Range[0, 4]

(* {{0, -1}, {1, -1 + 1/E}, {2, -1 + 2/E^2}, {3, -1 + 3/E^3}, {4, -1 + 4/E^4}} *)

p42[x_] = Fit[XY2, {1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4}, x]

(* -1. + 0.840339 x - 0.62339 x^2 + 0.166417 x^3 - 0.0154865 x^4 *)

Plot[{p42[x], f[x]}, {x, 0, 4},
 PlotStyle -> {Green, Red},
 PlotRange -> All,
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {0.75, 0.75}],
 Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02], Point[XY2]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, that helped a lot and it is helping me see how interpolation should look graphically! I appreciate the corrections!